# "Gradle Dependencies" cannot be correctly shown in 'Apache Tomcat' Run Configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, gradle

My environment is as below:
    Eclipse: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1) -- Build id: 20140925-1800
    Gradle IDE: 3.6.3.201411271013-RELEASE

I have one project 'webapp' with gradle dependencies. If I create one 'Java Application' Run configuration, 
the "Gradle Dependencies" could be correctly displayed, and also be effective. See below pictures:
[image: good]

If I create one 'Apache Tomcat' Run Configuration to add the 'webapp' project in 'Classpath' tab, then 
the "Gradle Dependencies" couldn't be correctly displayed, and also not effective. See below pictures:
[image: bad]

Normally, I need to manually add all those gradle-dependencies jars in the 'Classpath' tab to solve the "ClassNotFoundException". Like this:
[image: manual]

However, it's not convenient.
Does anyone meet the same problem? Thanks.

Comment: are you using the eclipse-wtp plugin?

Comment: Hi, I'm not using "apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'" in my gradle build file.

Answer (score 0):

Generating the Eclipse project using the Gradle [eclipse-wtp](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseWtp.html) plugin and than importing the generated project to Eclipse should fix this issue:

```
gradle cleanEclipse eclipse eclipseWtp
```

Comment: Thank you. However, it still doesn't work for my case.

Comment: Did you make sure that the old project .settings was cleaned before creating a new one?

Comment: Yes, the old project .settings was cleaned before creating a new one.